# Understanding a non-autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x'(t) = a(t)x$

a) Find a formula involving integrals for the solution of this system.
b) Prove that your formula gives the general solution of this system.

I am new to ODE's and we have gone over integrating the system...
$x'/x = a(t)$ in order to attempt to isolate x in terms of $t$.  I thus get $log(x) = 0.5at^2+C \; \text{(a constant)}$, which yields $x(t) = e^(.5at^2+C)$, not sure if I'm right here.  I'm also not sure why it says "involving integrals," making it sound like the solution needs integral signs in it?

For part b, I have no idea how to even start it, not sure what I need to show.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The right hand side is wrong. $a(t)$ is a function of $t$, so its integral is not $0.5 at^2$ (that is the integral of $a$ times $t$).

Comment: I edited your question to get the $\LaTeX$ working properly.  Remember to enclose your math with "\$" signs; thus "\$ \int_a^b f(t) \;dt\$" produces $\int_a^b f(t) \; dt$.  Cheers!

Comment: Also, rpa is right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From

$x'(t) = a(t)x(t) \tag 1$

we write

$(\ln x(t))' = \dfrac{x'(t)}{x(t)} = a(t); \tag 2$

whence

$\ln \left ( \dfrac{x(t)}{x(t_0)} \right ) = \ln x(t) - \ln x(t_0) = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t \dfrac{x'(t)}{x(t)} \; dt = \int_{t_0}^t a(t) \; dt, \tag 3$

or

$\dfrac{x(t)}{x(t_0)} = \exp \left ( \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t a(t) \; dt \right ), \tag 4$

or

$x(t) = x(t_0) \exp \left ( \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t a(t) \; dt \right ), \tag 5$

which solves part ***(a)***.

We note that the division by $x(t)$ occurring in (2) is legitimate when $x(t) \ne 0$.  If $x(t_0) = 0$ for some $t_0$, then $x(t) = 0$ is the unique solution to (1) with $x(t_0) = 0$.  Therefore a solution initialized with $x(t_0) > 0$ will remain positive for all $t$; likewise a solution with $x(t_0) < 0$ will remain negative, and thus step (2) is valid, as is corroborated by equation (5).

For part ***(b)*** We have shown that $x(t)$ satisfying (1) with $x(t_0) \ne 0$ at *some* $t$ *must* be of the form (5); (5) is a *necessary* condition for (1) to apply.  Therefore, (5), being the *only* solution, is completely general in the sense that it binds for *any* initial condition $x(t_0)$; it is as general as one could wish.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $$x'(t) = a(t)\,x(t)$$ then
$$\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}=a(t)$$
$$\int\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}\,dt=\int a(t)\,dt \implies \log (|x(t)|)=\int a(t)\,dt+C\implies x(t)=C \, e^{\int a(t)\,dt }$$